# Can't get Vue animations to behave as desired

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3

I need to copy [this animation](https://dribbble.com/shots/3969194-Travel-Agency-Landing-Page) and I'm having some trouble getting all the parts to work.  So far I have it working up to the point where the text box flies in, however when I try to close the text box the animations don't toggle back.  The `<Transtion>` component resets all the animations one they're done instead of leaving them in their ending state which made me have to add event listeners to set styles manually to mak them stay.  I'm at a loss and don't know what to do, can someone help e figure this out?  Below is my Vue component.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref} from 'vue';
  import type { Ref } from 'vue';
  import {onMounted} from 'vue';
  import {animate} from 'motion';

  let plusButtonComplete: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
  let plusButtonClicked: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
  let titleAnimationComplete: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
  let textFrameAnimationComplete: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
  let closeTextFrameClicked: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);

  onMounted(()=>{

    const animatedTitle = document.getElementById('animatedTitle');
    const textFrame = document.getElementById('textFrame');

    document.getElementById('plusButton')!.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
     plusButtonComplete.value = true;
     plusButtonClicked.value = false;
     console.log('button complete', plusButtonComplete);
    });
    
    animatedTitle!.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
     animatedTitle!.style.opacity = '0';
     titleAnimationComplete.value = true;
     console.log('title complete', titleAnimationComplete);
    });

    textFrame!.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
      textFrameAnimationComplete.value = true;
      textFrame!.style.height = '100%';
      textFrame!.style.width = '100%';
      textFrame!.style.borderRadius = '0';
      textFrame!.style.top = '0';
      document.getElementById('textContainer')!.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    })

    
  });
  
  const toggleBack = ()=>{
    console.log('toggle clicked');
    document.getElementById('textFrame')!.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('animatedTitle')!.style.opacity = '1';
    plusButtonClicked.value = false;
    closeTextFrameClicked.value = true;
    console.log(plusButtonClicked.value, closeTextFrameClicked.value);
  }
</script>

<template>
  <section class="page bg-cover w-full h-full grid-cols-12 grid-rows-6">

    <div class="bg-burgundy
              row-start-1
              row-span-6
              col-start-1
              sm:col-end-4"
    ></div>

    <h1 v-show="!plusButtonComplete"
       class="title
              text-right
              sm:col-start-3
              md:col-start-2
              lg:col-start-1
              sm:col-span-9
              sm:row-start-3
              sm:row-span-2
              bg-white
              sm:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-2)]
              md:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-5)]"
    >
      Explore
    </h1>

    <Transition name="titleAnimation">
      <h1 id="animatedTitle"
          v-show="plusButtonComplete"
          class="title
              text-right
              sm:col-start-3
              md:col-start-2
              lg:col-start-1
              sm:col-span-9
              sm:row-start-3
              sm:row-span-2
              bg-white
              sm:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-2)]
              md:text-[length:var(--text-ultraJumbotron-5)]"
    >
      Explore
    </h1>
    </Transition>

    <img class="
               .plusButton
               sm:w-[var(--xTiny-1-3)]
               col-start-3
               col-end-4
               row-start-5
               row-end-6
               "
      v-show="!plusButtonClicked"
      @click="plusButtonClicked = true"
      src="./assets/Plus.svg"
    />
    <p class="
        details
        text-white
        align-center
        sm:text-[length:var(--text-widget-3)]
        md:text-[length:var(--text-article-3)]
        col-start-3
        col-end-9
        row-start-5
        row-end-6"
    >
      more details
    </p>

    <Transition name="plusButtonAnimation">
      <img v-show="plusButtonClicked"
           class=".plusButton
           sm:w-[var(--xTiny-1-3)]
           col-start-3
           col-end-4
           row-start-5
           row-end-6"
           id="plusButton"
           src="./assets/Plus.svg"
      />
    </Transition>

    <section class="
              textContainer
              col-start-3
              sm:col-end-11
              md:col-end-10
              lg:col-end-6
              row-start-2
              row-end-6"
              id="textContainer"
    >
  
      <Transition name="textFrameAnimation">
        <article
          v-show="plusButtonComplete"
          id="textFrame"
          class="textFrame
                sm:w-[var(--xTiny-1-3)]
                sm:h-[var(--xTiny-1-3)]
                bg-white z-70"
        >
        
          <article id="textContent">
            <p @click="toggleBack()" class="closeButton text-burgundy text-[length:var(--text-article-3)]">X</p>

            <article class="contentShell">
              <h2 class="contentTitle
                        text-burgundy
                         text-[length:var(--text-title-3)]"
              >
                Explore
              </h2>

              <p class="text-[length:var(--text-caption-1)]">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean. Id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi. Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit.
              </p>

              <button class="
                            readMoreButton
                            my-5
                            text-[length:var(--text-widget-1)]
                            text-white
                            tracking-widest"
              >
                READ MORE

              </button>

            </article>

          </article>

        </article>
      </Transition>

      <Tansition name="goBackAnimation">
        <article
          v-show="closeTextFrameClicked"
          id="textFrameB"
          class="textFrame
                bg-white
                z-70"
        ></article>
      </Tansition>

    </section>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>

.page{
  display: grid;
  background-image: url('./assets/background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
  .title{
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    align-self: left;
    width: min-content;
    text-align: left;
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 5%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background-size: 130%;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }

  .plusBtnContainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-area: 2/2/3/3;
    justify-self: left;
    align-self: start;
    column-gap: var(--micro-1-5);
    grid-template-columns: var(--xTiny-1-3) auto;
  }
  .buttonShell{
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .plusButton{
    /*grid-area: 1/1/2/2;*/
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    /*justify-self: left;*/
    /*justify-self: flex-start;
    align-self: end;*/
  }

  .textContainer{
    pointer-events: none;

  }
  .textFrame{
    grid-area: 5/3/6/4;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    /*justify-self: flex-start;*/
    /*position:absolute;*/
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
  }

  .textContent{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }

  .closeButton{
    justify-self: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .contentTitle{
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
  }

  .contentShell{
    width: 77%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .readMoreButton{
    display: block;
    padding: var(--micro-1-1) var(--xTiny-1-3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
    rgba(97, 24, 24, 1),
    rgba(163, 103, 84, 1));
  }

  .details{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }

  @keyframes plusButtonAnimationSequence{
    0% {transform: scale(1)}
    70% {transform: scale(0.4)}
    98% {transform: scale(1.1)}
    100% {transform: scale(1)}
  }
  .plusButtonAnimation-enter-active{
    animation: plusButtonAnimationSequence .3s ease-out;
  }

  @keyframes titleAnimationSequence{
    0% {
      background-position-x: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position-x: -700%;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    }
  }
  .titleAnimation-enter-active{
    animation: titleAnimationSequence .5s ease-out forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes textFrameAnimationSequence{
    0% {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      border-radius: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }

  .textFrame-animation-leave-active{
    animation: goBackAnimationSequence .5s ease-out forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes textFrameAnimationLeaveSequence{
    0%{
      border-radius: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    100%{
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: 50vh;
      width: var(--xTiny-1-3);
      height: var(--xTiny-1-3);
    }
  }

  .textFrameAnimation-enter-active{
    animation: textFrameAnimationSequence .5s ease-out forwards;
  }



  @media(min-width: 500px){
    .plusBtnContainer{
      grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
      align-self: last baseline;
    }
  }

  @media(min-width: 1014px){
    .titleArea{
      grid-template-columns: var(--small-2-4) auto 1fr;
    }
  }
</style>
```